# Adding Json data to array in ReactJs

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, sorting, search

I have a JSON file which has a list of elements enclosed in an array. I want to fetch the data from this JSON nfile store them in an array in ReactJS to create a table .I followed this tutorial [How to load a json file in reactjs](http://4dev.tech/2017/12/how-to-load-a-json-file-in-reactjs/) and did achieve in displaying the elements. I need to store them in an array so that i can pass it to another component. Also, any ideas on how to perform a search and also sort the elements in the table.

Comment: You said you achieved displaying the data, so you must have succeeded in importing the data. So they should already be stored in an array which you can pass to another component. What did you try and what's your *specific* issue (including console errors and such)? Also "perform a search" is very vague, and with no other context I doubt you'll get help there. As for sorting an array of objects, there's tons of stuff online about that, Google it.

Comment: I am working on a mini project. In, my project, I have a webserver setup running python scripts which dumps errors to a JSON file. My objective is to render this JSON data array into reactJS and perform a search in the ReactJs code. For example searching a for a string (partial or full match) in the array. This is the context. I do not know where to start working from